# Step by Step of Using JOBB tool to Create Expansion Files

Tags: android, apk, apk-expansion-files

I want to upload an APK file to Google Play, but the file exceeds the size of 50MB as I have over 600 images in the **drawable** package. I have searched the Internet, but could not find a good easy explanation of how to split the apk file to come up with expansion files.

Could anyone provide ***step by step of very simple example*** how to use JOBB tool and what modifications are need to be done in the application source file (in JAVA). I have found pages of Stack Overflow, but they do not show step-by-step simple easy to understand example.

For your kind information, I am using Android Studio.

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm having the same issue at this moment

Comment: did you maybe get this working yet?